# UIButton not setting alpha properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

This is probably a stupid mistake of mine, but I have 3 UIbuttons, 2 of which are hidden by default, and 1 which is supposed to reveal the 2 others when clicked on. I call this method in my viewDidLoad:

```
-(void) initButtons
{
self.checkbutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 330, 80, 70)];
self.checkbutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.checkbutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbutton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.checkbutton.enabled = NO;
self.checkbutton.alpha = 0.0;
[self.view addSubview:self.checkbutton];

self.xbutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 330, 70, 70)];
self.xbutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.xbutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"X.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.xbutton.enabled = NO;
self.xbutton.alpha = 0.0;
[self.view addSubview:self.xbutton];
}
```

And when my visible button is clicked, this method is called:

```
-(void) showbuttons
{
    self.checkbutton.enabled = YES;
    [[self checkbutton] setAlpha:1.0];

    self.xbutton.enabled = YES;
    [[self xbutton] setAlpha:1.0];

    NSLog(@"xbutton alpha: %f", [[self xbutton] alpha]);
    NSLog(@"checkbutton alpha: %f", [[self checkbutton] alpha]);
}
```

What happens is that when I click the visible button, only 1 button appears. (xbutton) They should be coded in the exact same way, I don't know what's wrong. The NSLogs that I have show that both buttons have an alpha value of 1.0. I'm sure I @propertied and @synthesized checkbutton correctly, it's just like the xbutton.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, a side question: what's the difference between `[checkbutton setAlpha]` and `[self.checkbutton setAlpha]`?

Ughh... My fault. My image was named checkmark.png and not checkbutton.png. Thanks to @DanielRHicks for answering my side question though.

Comment: The difference between the `self` and non-`self` versions of `@synthesized` properties on REFERENCE is negligible -- the first uses the getter while the second references the instance variable directly.  The difference on ASSIGNMENT, of course, is substantial, since the first manages retaining (if defined that way) while the second sets the instance variable without any retain management.

Comment: @Daniel When you say assignment, do you mean any setting of values? (like setAlpha) Or just when you're allocating and initializing it?

Comment: `self.object = someObject;` is equivalent to `setObject(someObject);`.  But `object = someObject;` is NOT equivalent to either of the others, and if the property `object` is being retained, that last assignment will fail to retain it (and likewise fail to unretain the previous value in the property), leading to a likely storage bug and crash.

Answer (score 1):

hidden and alpha are different

3 UIbuttons, 2 of which are hidden by default, and 1 which is supposed to reveal the 2 others when clicked on.

you say that they are hidden by default

maybe you should try

self.checkbutton.hidden = NO

Answer (score 0):

are you setting the hidden property initially to YES?  if so you will also have to do

```
self.xbutton.hidden = NO
```

on the buttons